# Why does my Scala list disappear in the following code?

Tags: scala

```
val files = new File("data").list()
val filtered = files.filter(name => name.contains("txn"))
val masterList = new ListBuffer[String]
for (file <- filtered) {
  val lines = Source.fromFile(new File("data\\" + file), "UTF-16").getLines
  val cleaned = lines.filter(!masterList.contains(_))
  println("*" + cleaned.length)
  cleaned.foreach(println(_))
  println("**" + cleaned.length)
  cleaned.foreach(masterList.append(_))
}
```

The output from the code is as follows

```
*175
**0
```

I don't understand why my list disappears

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`cleaned` is an iterator.

```
scala> val cleaned = lines.filter(_!="")
cleaned: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator
```

Right after assigning it is non-empty. Iterators in scala are single-used - once you traversed it (e.g. by applying `length` method) it becomes empty:

```
scala> cleaned.length
res0: Int = 13

scala> cleaned.length
res1: Int = 0
```

You can fix that behavior by converting to List, or to Seq (lazy):

```
scala> val lines=Source.fromFile("bla.txt").getLines
lines: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> val cleaned = lines.filter(_!="").toSeq
cleaned: Seq[String] = Stream(first, ?)

scala> cleaned.length
res4: Int = 13

scala> cleaned.length
res5: Int = 13
```

Comment: Wow. This behavior have just caught me off-guard. Never thought that a harmless call to `length` actually destroys the whole thing!

Comment: thats the better word. omnomnomnomm

Answer (score 6):

`Source.fromFile(new File("data\\" + file), "UTF-16").getLines` returns an `Iterator[String]`. Filtering still returns an `Iterator`. Calling `length` on an iterator will cause it to be read fully until `hasNext` returns false. The second time around, it's empty. Similar to:

```
scala> val cleaned = List(1,2).iterator
cleaned: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> cleaned.length
res10: Int = 2

scala> cleaned.length
res11: Int = 0
```