# Why does the length function seems to delete the list?

Tags: scala

I have this code snippet:

```
 for (f <- file_list){
                  val file_name = path + "\\" + f + ".txt"
                  val line_list = Source.fromFile(file_name).getLines()
                  println (file_name + ": " + line_list.length)
                  println (file_name + ": " + line_list.length)
                  total_number_lines += line_list.size
              }
```

I have a list of files, for each of them I open it, load it as a list of its lines and then I count the number of lines in the list.

The former call to `line_list.length` gives the right values of line number, but the latter one always returns zero. Actually, after the `length` function is executed, the `line_list` list seems to be empty.

I really cannot understand why is that.

What I am missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my Scala list disappear in the following code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138671/why-does-my-scala-list-disappear-in-the-following-code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Source.getLines()` returns an `Iterator[String]`, not a collection, so calling `.length` on it will completely consume it.

You can use `Source.fromFile(file_name).getLines().toList` if you want to go through it several times.

Answer (score 5):

`getLines()` returns an [`Iterator[String]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator) and you can only traverse an iterator once. Calling `length` exhausts the iterator, so subsequent calls to `length` and `size` are being called when the end has being reached, hence it appearing empty:

> It is of particular importance to note that, unless stated otherwise,
>   one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it. The two
>   most important exceptions are also the sole abstract methods: next and
>   hasNext.